# Django java_script (ajax) скрипт не видит url заданный в виде url:"{% url 'main' %}",

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django, ajax

Проект на django, в котором использую js скрипт(+ ajax).
Локальный url/адрес: http://127.0.0.1:8000/umbrella/main.
Есть такой.
url.py

```py
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [path("main", main, name='main')]      // main - который далее будет в js исполь-ся
```

затем в скрипте:
test.js

```js
const contact_us = document.getElementById("send_114")
contact_us.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      console.log("clicked !");
      $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:"{% url 'main' %}",    // <------ ругается на эту запись, почему то не видит данный url пишет: Not found /umbrella/{% url 'main' %}
        data:{
            csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
            email_value : document.getElementById("input_email").value,
            action: 'ajax_send_zayvka'                              // 
        },
        success:function(data){
        alert(data)
        },
        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) .....
    }
    });
})
```

Не пойму почему не видит запись вида: `{% url 'main' %}` , в других проектах использовал все работало норм :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Файл test.js не обрабатывается шаблонизатором. Если вы хотите использовать теги django в js скриптах вам нужно их либо явно описывать в шаблоне `<script>...</script>`, либо предварительно обрабатывать шаблонизатором.

Comment: а ведь точно ), я как раз ранее скрипт использовал внутри шаблона, не в отдельном js файле

Comment: предварительно обрабатывать шаблонизатором нужно файл js ?

Comment: Ну вы можете сделать самописный middleware например, и перед тем как отдать файл js обработать его. Например для урлов /js/*.js можно сделать view который будет использовать https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string для этого

Comment: спасибо, попробую двигаться в данном направлении :)